# How do I manage conflicts between local git and github

Tags: git, github, git-pull

first time question. I'm doing a tutorial on git and covering the instance where the code on the server has been updated and the local code has been independently updated so there is a conflict.

In the video, the lecturer does a git pull and this tries to get the files. The dialog gets details then says

```
Auto-merging hello.html
```

but mine, at that stage, says

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        hello.html
```

I ended up not being able to push or pull changes until I resolved the conflict. I ended up having to do

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply --index
```

Is there a configuration I need to apply to my local git to get it to try the auto-merge?

for clarity I get

```
$ git pull
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        hello.html
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 7ed9dbb..0525225

Erik@DESKTOP-TI7OP0E MINGW64 /e/gitrepo/webcourse (master)
$ git commit -m "save"
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   hello.html

no changes added to commit
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to commit some changes?

Comment: Auto-merge tries its best, but it also works hard to not destroy your local changes. Here, it is telling you it cannot merge automatically because that would undo some of your work. Commit your changes, then merge, at which point you'll have a chance to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that when I do a pull it doesn't try to auto-merge. It just says my local changes would be lost and aborts. In the lecture it tries the auto-merge, then his local file shows the differences. He can then select the version he wants and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should commit your changes before trying the merge. When Git is trying to perform a merge, it will write the result, including any conflicts, into your working tree. However, if you have uncommitted changes, doing so would destroy them, so Git will abort so as not to cause you to lose data.

If you commit your changes and your working tree is clean, then Git knows that you have a saved copy of the work, and if you don't like the result of the merge or if there are conflicts, you won't lose data.

It is also possible, as you've noticed, to stash your changes and reapply them later. That will also make your working tree clean, which will make Git happy. Which choice is right depends on what you're doing. If your change logically belongs on the branch you're on, and you're okay with keeping it right now, then commit it; if you'd rather work on it later or on another branch, then stash it.

Comment: The issue there is Git says
'Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
 (use "git pull" to update your local branch)'
git pull fails because it wants me to commit my changes

Comment: `git pull` indeed fails here but it's not what bk2204 suggested to do. *Commit* beforehand. (Also, welcome to you :-)

Comment: The commit fails too, I've updated the question with the output from the pull and commit commands. It's a catch 22 situation. I can't commit until I've done a pull and I can't pull until I've done a commit.

Comment: My stupid. I misunderstood when you said commit. I was trying it at the wrong stage. Thanks for helping this newbie:)